# Complex Select Query with multiple conditions and orders

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, left-join, multiple-tables

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN offertran ot 
ON p.prod_id = ot.prod_id

LEFT JOIN Offers o
       ON ot.offer_id = o.id
      AND o.dF<=3 
      AND o.dt>=3

ORDER BY o.id DESC, 
          p.prod_id ASC
LIMIT 20
```

[Please check the output in fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3da57/3)

**I want the existing condition as it is and some more added conditions as listed below:**

1. In this output, I got Offered products are shown first (This is important, after this)
2. I want New products - that is sort based on `todaysDate - p.pdate less than 30 days`
3. Then show the products those have `p.pre != ''`
4. Then show them who dont have price ie. `p.price ==0`
5. Then arrange other products by `prod_id DESC`

**I want all in one, to add those 5 points in this existing query**

I hope you got the problem. I need an immediate response.
Thanks in advance

Comment: do u need it as separate query or add to existing?

Comment: The points you mentioned in 1 to 5 are just for sorting the final output you get using the query you posted?

Comment: I want all in one... to add those 5 points in this existing query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
SELECT p.*, o.id
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN offertran ot 
ON p.prod_id = ot.prod_id
LEFT JOIN Offers o
       ON ot.offer_id = o.id
      AND o.dF<=3 
      AND o.dt>=3
ORDER BY o.id DESC, 
case when p.pDate > curdate()-interval 30 day then p.pDate else '1970-01-01' end desc,
case when p.pre != '' then 1 else 0 end desc,
p.price asc,p.prod_id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

I am a little unclear what you mean in point 2:

Do you want the resulting dates sorted `DESC` or `ASC`? What happens to those rows with a date older than 30 days? Exclude? Drop into the next sorting level?

I've taken a guess at what you meant. I am sure you can play around with the query if I have misunderstood.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted.. I just modified little things.. you can see that here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3da57/9 and thanks u so much @Tom Mac

Comment: 2nd point was.. if the date interval is not in 30 days then that product should be sorted by `prod_id` like other products. this is also working there

Answer (score 0):

you simply have to add a WHERE condition...

```
SELECT p.*, o.id
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN offertran ot 
ON p.prod_id = ot.prod_id

LEFT JOIN Offers o
       ON ot.offer_id = o.id
      AND o.dF<=3 
      AND o.dt>=3

WHERE datediff(curdate(),p.pdate)<30
      AND p.pre <> ''
      AND p.price = 0

ORDER BY o.id DESC, 
         p.prod_id ASC,
         prod_id DESC

LIMIT 20
```